# Gimp: How to reverse the direction of gif image

Tags: gimp, animation, gif

How can i reverse Gif image with out affecting animation of the image and save it. I used Flip Tool and reversed image then after save it. Then i lost the animation effect of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Image -> Transform -> Flip Horizontally.
[image]

I had 2 layers and after flipping, the animation worked as expected. If you are having problem, could you upload your GIF somewhere and paste the link here so I could have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

File > Open as Layers - then > Image > Transform > Flip Horizontally - then > File > Export As

In the Export As dialogue box file name field give the file a .gif extension.

In the Export As Gif dialogue box select the As Animation tick box

Then select Export

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to do this using an online tool like https://gifreverse.com.  It's not directly in GIMP but for me it's faster because the process requires export/import and multiple menus when done natively.

Comment: OP was asking to horizontally flip the GIF, whereas that website reverses it in time.